# No reaction when pressing 'Login' button

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook iOS SDK for my app. I am using the sample's code for my login function asking for permissions and storing the returned token. However, locally on every iOS version on the simulator as well as on my iPhone4 it works. Some customers report that in their case pressing the login button does not show any reaction. Using google for research did not reveal any hints on that.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Address that question to Facebook IOS SDK support..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I had a problem like this.. I've changed "perms" to "scope" inside facebook login button, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Bug fixed. My fault, tested with Debug target only, which is why bug only appeared in Releases, since an #ifdef DEBUG was enabling/disabling the login function.